# Unable to view services under podman system command - macos

Tags: macos, podman

I have setup **podman** in my machine (macos) using brew command. Podman is working as expected but unable to view **service** option under **podman system** command.

Here I'm trying to use RESTFul command service but it is not working as expected.

Can any one please help ?

```
~ % podman --version
podman version 4.0.3
```

**Command used to start service** : `podman system service --time 5 &`

**Error Response** : Error: unknown flag: --time

Also I have checked further and found no **service** option under podman system

**Command** :

```
podman system --help
```

**Result** :

```
Manage podman

Description:
  Manage podman

Usage:
  podman system [command]

Available Commands:
  connection  Manage remote ssh destinations
  df          Show podman disk usage
  info        Display podman system information
  prune       Remove unused data
```

Comment: Can you run `podman system service -h` to make sure the command is running fine

Comment: Hi @Jaay, below is the response for above command.
$ podman system service -h
Error: pflag: help requested
See 'podman system --help'